# Dynamically Inserting Text Based On Dropdown In Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm trying to make an automated report form in Word 2007 without using a lot of scripts that I don't have time to learn. Basically, the first page is a table with a bunch of dropdown fields. When the user selects something on one of the drop down fields, it inserts the item as a bullet point in the form on the next page, and then the user can just print off that page.

The process that I'm following now is that I'll insert a dropdown in developer mode, create a reference bookmark for it, and then in the document area I'll hit ctrl+f9 and insert `{REF bookmarktitle}`

The problem with this message is it only displays the actual text that displays in the dropdown, and it is incredibly hard to format in the document.

I've also tried to use an IF statement as follows:

{IF "{bkmarktitle}" = "value" "True" "False"}

but this never works for some reason and always resorts to the false value.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of problems using drop down content controls and bookmarks. If your controls are on separate paragraphs then assign a custom style to the paragraph and use STYLEREF instead.